# How to get return from webAPI which will redirect to other page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Below is my post imformation

```
 content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
                    new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PlatFormId", m.MERCHANTID),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("HashKey", "xxxxxx"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ReCheckId", m.ORDERID),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Amount", Amount),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("PayType", m.PAYTYPE),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("RefundDesc", "xxxx"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CancelFrom", "1")

                    }
                );

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var responseJson = httpClient.PostAsync(Url, content)
                .Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

When I post to webAPI . Result is like this picture.
[This is API's result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g4HV.png)

This API receive a post will redirect another page.
And do some calculate then redirect final page.
I am use ASP.NET MVC.
How to post these message and get final page's result.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Disable the redirect on the `HttpClient`?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. API stands for *Application* Programming Interface. It means that the client is another application, not a human. It makes absolutely no sense to redirect from an API controller to somewhere else - an API needs to be stable for another application to connect to it. That redirect should be done in the application that *calls* the API (that is, the application the *user* is looking at which presumably is the MVC application).